# can not execute tags in text enter text area element

Tags: javascript, html

I use HTML5 and textara element. 
 I write funcation by javascript to put string in textara element :

```
var textBoxPacket = document.getElementById("TextArea1");
textBoxPacket.innerHTML = textBoxPacket.innerHTML +"<br>" +"You say: <strong>" + TxtSend.value + "</strong>";
```

my problem is : the HTML tags don't execute . the browser show them text and dont execute them . what is problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text areas only support plaintext, you can't use html inside them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

If you need html, use a different tag with the contenteditable attribute and style it to look like a textarea.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: I try use variable string to store inside it after than put inside textarea  but variable string dosent accept innerHTML

Comment: You can't use textarea in this way. Try something like: `<div contenteditable><br>You say: <strong>TxtSend.value</strong></div>` and give it some css so that it looks like a text area. Else you're stuck with not using <br> and <strong> inside the textarea. If you only need breaks and bold, you can use the html entity &#10; for a new line inside a textarea.

Comment: There isn't one as far as I know. Hence you shouldn't use a textarea if you have to style the text in a way.